# How do you connect to a Multi-Instance Queue Manager using MQQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: java, tomcat, ibm-mq

We have an application which needs to communicate with a Multi-Instance QueueManager. Both (instances) are running on the default port and have unique addresses.

- serverA.internal.company.address
- serverB.internal.company.address

We use the following code to establish the ConnectionFactory:

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
connectionFactory.setPort(1414);
connectionFactory.setChannel("CLIENTCONNECTION");
connectionFactory.setQueueManager("queue.manager.name.here");
connectionFactory.setHostName("serverA.internal.company.address");
```

How can we specify both addresses so that failover is achieved without writing our own retry logic?

Comment: I found someone with a very similar issue (http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=57240&sid=02cc89b38c7795d2571155e1e3866aa5)  on mqseries.net but their solution does not seem like it is applicable.

Comment: connectionFactory.setConnectionNameList(string) might do the trick. I'm going to investigate.

Comment: a similar question was asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975618/mqqueuemanager-multiple-instance-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

using the following:

```
connectionFactory.setConnectionNameList("serverA.internal.company.address(1414),"
                                      + "serverB.internal.company.address(1414)")
```

instead of

```
connectionFactory.setHostName("serverA.internal.company.address");
connectionFactory.setPort(1414);
```

did the trick for us.

Answer (score 5):

You are on exactly the correct track - but please do review this technote for information.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508357

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the great article. +1 for this.