# How do you connect to a Multi-Instance MQSeries Queue Manager using properties?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

The following question:

[How do you connect to a Multi-Instance Queue Manager using MQQueueConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010066/how-do-you-connect-to-a-multi-instance-queue-manager-using-mqqueueconnectionfact)

asks how to connect to a Multi-Instance Queue Manager using MQQueueConnectionFactory, exactly as it reads. What I want is something similar but not the same: How to connect to a Multi-Instance Queue Manager not using MQConnectionFactory, but using properties:

```
Hashtable properties;
MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager( QMGR_NAME, properties );
```

Currently we are connecting to a single instance by setting the following properties:

```
MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY
MQC.PORT_PROPERTY
MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY
MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY (set to MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT)
```

What properties should we set to connect to a multi-instance queue manager?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/multi_instance_qms.htm

Comment: That link is to a MQFTE Knowledge center and does not apply directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the IBM MQ Classes for Java, the linked question is discussing the IBM MQ Classes for JMS.

The v8.0 Knowledge center page "[Multi-instance queue managers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018140_.htm)" it states the following:

> Automatic client reconnect is not supported by IBM MQ classes for
>   Java™.

Please note that per the v9.0 Knowledge center page "[Using IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030520_.htm)", IBM MQ Classes for Java have been functionally stabilized at the level shipped in IBM MQ Version 8.0.

> IBM will make no further enhancements to the IBM MQ classes for Java
>   and they are functionally stabilized at the level shipped in IBM MQ
>   Version 8.0.

Multi-Instance was introduced in v7.0 and since the IBM MQ Classes for Java have not been updated to support reconnect and are now stabilized it is unlikely it would be added.

It would be recommended to migrate to IBM MQ Classes for JMS if you require this functionality.